# Is there an undirected tree graph with all vertices with the same degree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I'm trying to draw an undirected tree graph such that all vertices have the same degree, but it seems that I can't.

Is it possible? I'd love an example. If it's not possible, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tree on $n\geq 1$ vertices has $n-1$ edges. Therefore, if all the vertices have the same degree $d\geq 0$ then
$$dn=\sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)=2(n-1)$$
that is $(2-d)n=2$ which has two solutions: i) $d=1$ and $n=2$; ii) $d=0$ and $n=1$.

What may we conclude?

Comment: so if the total degree is $2(n-1)$ and I have $n$ vertexes, so it is only possible when $\frac{2(n-1)}{n}$ will give me a whole number. 

Which is only for n=1 and n= 2.

Right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an undirected tree graph whose vertices all have the same degree $d$, and not only is this possible for the case where $d=0$ or $d=1$ as mentioned in other answers; but such tree exists for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$, provided you allow the tree to have infinitely many vertices.

This is called a [*regular tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Types_of_trees) of degree $d$, they arise for example as the Cayley graph of free groups.

With degree $d=2$, you can label your vertices by the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and say that there is an edge between two vertices if they differ by one. It is essentially a dotted line whose vertices are the dots.

With degree $d=3$, the regular tree looks like this:
[image: Regular tree of degree 3]

The [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) generated by two elements is the regular tree with $d=4$, which looks like this:
[image: Regular tree of degree 4]

The proofs provided in other replies assume that the tree has finitely many vertices; in one by counting the number of edges; in the other by assuming that the tree must have a leaf, which is only true for finite trees.

Comment: @amWhy I have now updated the answer to provide an answer to the question. Let me know if there's any further clarification you would recommend adding.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known fact that every tree has at least one leaf, i.e. a vertex of degree 1 (unless of course the tree is trivial, in which case you have only one vertex and its degree is 0). To see this, take a path P of maximum length. If the last vertex of P has degree strictly more than 1, then one its neighbours would have to lie on P (otherwise P would not have maximum length), but that would form a cycle which is not possible.

So in every tree there is a vertex of degree 1. This means that in order to have a tree where all vertices have the same degree, that degree would have to be exactly 1. The only way this would be possible would be if the tree had exactly 2 vertices.